# Tabs in android not showing

Tags: java, android, xml

I have searched a lot for this topic but atlast i have to ask it in here because i know i will get the right answer. I want to have three tabs in my xml page but only "Tab label" is written on it. here is my main xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

and here is my java file:

```
    package com.example.hi_5physics;

    import android.app.TabActivity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.TabHost;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public class Astronomytab extends TabActivity {
    private TabHost mTabHost;


@Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.astronomy);

     mTabHost = getTabHost();
        mTabHost.setup();


    Intent intentAndroid1 = new Intent().setClass(this, Faqs.class);
    TabHost.TabSpec tab1 = mTabHost
                    .newTabSpec("Android")
                    .setIndicator("Rankings")
                    .setContent(intentAndroid1);


    Intent intentAndroid2 = new Intent().setClass(this, Contactus.class);
    TabHost.TabSpec tab2 = mTabHost
                    .newTabSpec("Android")
                    .setIndicator("My Team")
                    .setContent(intentAndroid2);

        mTabHost.addTab(tab1);
        mTabHost.addTab(tab2);
}}
```

Please help me out.

Comment: Try from here: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/

Comment: check that tab icon is working or not?